# The Android Dalvik file (.dex) does not exist

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

This is Bush George.

I have developed one adf mobile app. When I am trying to deploy the app i am getting error

**The Android Dalvik file (.dex) does not exist.**

the following is the deployment log of my application

```
[05:43:35 PM] Updating Android profile dependencies with FAR profiles created from application projects...<br>
[05:43:35 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ---- <br>
[05:43:35 PM] Target platform is  (Android).<br>
[05:43:35 PM] Beginning deployment of ADF Mobile application "HelloWorld" to Android using profile "Android1".<br>
[05:43:35 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...<br>
[05:43:36 PM] Android Debug Bridge server already running.<br>
[05:43:40 PM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...<br>
[05:43:40 PM] Running dependency analysis...<br>
[05:43:40 PM] Building...<br>
[05:43:41 PM] Deploying 3 profiles...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Wrote Archive Module to F:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.adf.mobile\Samples\HelloWorld\ApplicationController\deploy\ApplicationController.jar<br>
[05:43:42 PM] WARNING: No Resource Catalog enabled ADF components found to package<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Wrote Archive Module to <br>F:\Oracle\Middleware2\jdeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.adf.mobile\Samples\HelloWorld\ViewController\deploy\ViewController.jar<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Starting to prepare the packaging...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Verifying existence of the .adf source directory of the ADF Mobile application...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Verifying Application Controller project exists...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Verifying application dependencies...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Verifying project dependencies...<br>
[05:43:42 PM] Validating application XML files...<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Validating XML files in project ApplicationController...<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Validating XML files in project ViewController...<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Copying FARs to the ADF Mobile Framework application...<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ApplicationController.jar" to deployment folder, "ApplicationController".<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Extracting Feature Archive file, "ViewController.jar" to deployment folder, "ViewController".<br>
[05:43:43 PM] Copying Android template...<br>
[05:43:59 PM] Copying framework resource files...<br>
[05:43:59 PM] Copying framework java resource files...<br>
[05:44:03 PM] Copying common javascript files...<br>
[05:44:12 PM] Deploying skinning files...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Copying application image files...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Copying ADF Mobile configuration files...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Copying .adf files...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Copying security related files to the ADF Mobile Framework application...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Creating Android preferences XML files...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Creating AndroidManifest.xml file...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Creating Google Cloud Messaging intent service file GCMIntentService.java...<br>
[05:44:14 PM] Creating unsigned Android application file...<br>
[05:44:36 PM] Compiling Android Resource Identifier file...<br>
[05:44:38 PM] Creating Android classes.dex file from class files...<br>
[05:44:38 PM] Updating unsigned Android application file with DEX file and .adf content...<br>
[05:44:38 PM] Deployment cancelled.<br>
[05:44:38 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.<br>
[05:44:38 PM] The Android Dalvik file (.dex) does not exist.(oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.ApkDeployer)
```

Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance.